# How to offset currency exchange losses?

Tags: foreign-exchange, eur-euro, foreign-currency

Situation forces me to repatriate foreign revenue valued in Euro to USA, which is not ideal at this moment because the Euro is at a low. To counter this, would it make sense to buy Euro in USA at the current low level while transferring and converting Euro in Dollar at the same time?

**Summarized:**

1. Transfer and exchange Euro for Dollar (forced step)
2. Buy Euro with the transferred dollar amount (voluntary step)
3. Convert Euro to USD at a more preferable rate (voluntary step)

Comment: What do steps 1 and 2 accomplish? It looks like you plan to exchange your Euro for USD, and then buy Euros with those USD, putting you back where you started, minus exchange fees.

Comment: @NuclearWang Yes, you are correct. I am forced to do Step 1. Step 2 would then offset Step 1.

Comment: You could hedge your exposure [using a currency ETF](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/forex/09/exchange-rate-risk-currency-etf.asp) (option)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I though repatriation was just an accounting mechanism. I'd check with a good CPA to see if you have to actually convert the funds to USD.

Comment: @DStanley True, it's not *forced* in that sense, but salaries need to be paid in USA.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Yes, that would be the plan. "buy Euro" could mean "buy Euro ETF".

Comment: OK, so how could you "buy euro" in step 2 if that money needs to go to salaries? Why not keep it in EUR and just convert it when needed?

Comment: As a follow up, what makes you assume that the Euro will not go even lower? You might hold onto your Euro and find that you get even fewer USD a year from now. The only real currency exchange loss is the percentage taken by whoever's converting the currency - the time of exchange, you have an equivalent amount of Euro and USD (minus fees). Beyond that, you're just playing the currency market. If you're really sure the Euro will go up, you should buy as much Euro as you can afford, not just with what you're transferring. If not, seek to minimize transaction fees.

Comment: In any case, you are essentially speculating on EUR/USD with step 2.

Comment: @NuclearWang Good point, the current low of the Euro is tied to debt problems in Italy. My expectation is that Euro will gain when that issue is resolved, but this indeed, can take years.

Comment: @DStanley That is correct.

Comment: My point is, if you can afford to "buy Euros" then you can afford to _keep_ the money in Euros and exchange later. Unless you plan to trade on margin or through CFDs, which is a horrible idea.

Comment: Just to check, you're expecting to wait some time between steps 2 and 3 in the hope that the exchange rate will move in your favour? If you execute step 3 immediately then you won't gain anything and will lose on transaction costs.

Comment: You are simply planning to "make a currency bet".   The past ("you lost some money on euros") means nothing.

Comment: You cannot "offset" something >once you've already had a loss<.  (Sadly!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title is: "**How to offset currency exchange losses**?"

However your course of action could alternately make the following a more accurate title: "**How to take on additional currency exposure / risk**?"

Remember - you are thinking of the EUR being at a 'low', but that's relative to some historical period. If EUR reaches parity with the USD, then you might look back at this in 2 years and think "why did I buy EUR when it was at a high?"

If you expect future expenses in EUR [ie: you expect to retire there, or perhaps you have a summer home there and make mortgage payments in EUR], then buying EUR in advance could be one way to mitigate that risk [AKA 'hedge' it].

However if you don't expect any significant expenses in EUR in the future, then **what you're really asking about is whether you should invest in a foreign currency**. And the answer to that is, **probably not**.

Currencies are poor investments, because they do not have an inherent growth proposition. You buy stocks, because companies make things, and if those companies grow, they make more things, and you get more dividends - there is a real-world value proposition. With currencies, even if Europe's economy expands, if the US's economy expands even more, *you could still lose money on your EUR investment*. That's because currencies are a *zero-sum game*. ie: if one goes up, it is because the other went down.

Also, currencies are quite volatile, and therefore risky - there are a lot of fx investing questions on this site that give a deeper explanation into all of that. For now the key for you to understand is simply that what you are planning *is* fx speculation, whether you think of it that way or not.

Comment: "Currencies are poor investments, because they do not have an inherent growth proposition." While your answer is generally good, this statement isn't really relevant. When you buy EUR with USD, you're exchanging USD currency for EUR currency. You're holding currency either way. Unless OP has need for cash, they shouldn't be holding either.

Comment: @Acccumulation Except in the case where your anticipated expenses are *also* in USD [ie: you live in the US and intend to continue with that], then you bear no currency risk. Holding cash is still not preferable, but you miss the point that holding a USD stock still bears USD-risk for non-US residents, and holding a EUR ETF bears EUR risk effectively the same as holding EUR cash as a US resident.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Huh? Of course you have currency risk. It's called "inflation".

Comment: @Acccumulation If you hold shares of a European company, and the USD strengthens relative to the EUR, as a US resident your shares will be worth less USD [the currency you use to eat]. As a European resident, this doesn't really impact you at all. This is an example of the type of risk from holding a foreign currency-denominated asset. It is a little odd that you are trying to say that currency risk doesn't exist.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I specifically said you *do* have currency risk. However, the example you give is not a good one, as a weakening of the EUR will likely result in an increase in the nominal price of European companies. If the EUR/USD exchange rate is changing because of EUR inflation, and the nominal price of European stocks doesn't increase, then European residents absolutely *will* be affected.